# MySQL query one table based on sum of records or no records in another table

Tags: mysql, select, join, left-join

I'm struggling to select records from a table of locations (eg hotels) based on their availability stored in a seperate table. To avoid having lots of availability records for every possible day/location combo, the availability table only holds records for limited or no availability for a given date - so the absence of a matching record means there is FULL availabilty.

The tables are a bit like...

> locations: id, name, maxRooms etc.
>
> availability: locationID, date, roomsAvailable( an integer from zero meaning no availability to maxRooms)

...and what I need to do is to select all locations who - for a given date period - have some availability. That means they either have no matching availability records (ie fully available) or the sum of their matching availability.roomsAvailable records is greater than zero.

I'm getting a headache just trying to explain this :-( any ideas gratefully received...

Comment: I'm sure if you show us some tables with the raw data and then the expected result, you will more easily state the question and most likely get an answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT locations.id FROM locations LEFT JOIN availability
    ON( locations.id = availability.locationID AND
        ( availability.roomsAvailable > 0 OR ISNULL( availability.locationID ) ) )
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a [LEFT JOIN](http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqlleftjoin.php)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can query like this, get all locations whose sum of rooms available are greater than 0 for a specific date, then get all locations that are not listed in availability.

```
SELECT * FROM locations 
WHERE id in 
(
  SELECT locationId
  FROM availability
  WHERE date >= '2011-05-01' and date <= '2011-07-01'
  GROUP by locationId
  HAVING SUM(roomsAvailable) > 0
) 
OR id not in (SELECT DISTINCT locationId FROM availabilty)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your suggestions everyone. After considering them I came up with this combined PHP/MySQL solution - which only works on MySQL 4 or later ...

SELECT * FROM locations
WHERE locations.id NOT IN (
      SELECT distinct availability.locationID
                    FROM availability
                    WHERE availability.date >= '$periodStartYMD' 
                          AND availability.date <= '$periodEndYMD'
                    GROUP BY locationID
                    HAVING sum(availability.availableRooms) = 0
                    AND count(availability.locationID) = $daysInPeriod)

the PHP vars should be self explanatory.

To summarise - If there are less availability records than days in the period that indicates full availability for the missing day records. If there IS a record, it indicates no or limited availability..

The sub-select statement gets all availability records matching a location which have a total availability of zero and ( the bit that was eluding me) a count of matching records totalling the number of days in the period.

So if there is an availability record for every day AND the total availability count is zero there must be no rooms available for the whole period.

Phew - hope that makes some sort of sens and thanks again...